What was used between these countertop sections?
Recently bought a home and the kitchen countertop seems to have been laid down in sections. Some of the sealant between the sections is cracking and I was wondering what was used so that I can re-do it. also, is anyone able to tell me what the countertops are made of? Quartz?




The middle picture looks like tiles with grout between them  with a type of caulking/sealer on top of the grout.

Your countertops are a type of granite.
It looks like an amateur install with unsanded grout between the seams.

I agree.  A professional installation uses specialized epoxies mixed on site for color- and hardness- matching.  It's nearly invisible and remains that way for the life of the counter.  If you are going to put money into this, call a local stone yard and ask for a labor-only quote to redo the joints the way they do new ones.

Thanks! The dishwasher died and when I went to pull it out, it seems they installed the countertop around it and the bottom of the stone lip is about 1/4 inch too long for me to get it out. I was hoping I could just remove those lip sections to get it out and put them back later.

Usually the rollers or feet on the dishwasher can be lowered.

Yeah I lowered them completely and still don't have quite enough room

@Visionvoid While it looks like sanded grout, if you're lucky it might not be.  It could just be some old, dried-out black caulk, which would make it much easier to remove the slab(s) blocking the dishwasher.  Pick at an unseen location with something sharp like the tip of an ice pick and see if it's hard and gritty like grout or (used-to-be?) gooey like caulk.

@andrewhenle I picked at it a bit and it came off as a black powder. So grout then?

It's unsanded grout.

Could use an oscillating multitool to dig it out some, and hopefully pry the apron pieces off intact for reinstall after dealing with the DW.  Perhaps have the height shortened to clear the DW upon reinstall.

The grout will fracture long before the granite. I don't think it is necessary to dig it out. The grout is a filler, not a bonding agent.

So I found some extra of the countertop skirt material in the garage. Out of curiosity I tried to snap it in half by hand and it did so very easily. Is that normal or is this something other than granite?

In the form you have found it, it is common to break easily. Big sections can fracture if not supported.
